# Javascript equivalent to Ruby's single quotes?

Tags: javascript, string

In Ruby, if you use single quotes to make a string, the program parses it so that the output is literally what you wrote.

For example, if you create a string the following way:

```
variable_a = 'my\nname\nis\nOliver\nQueen'
```

the output of `puts variable_a` is

```
>>my\nname\nis\nOliver\nQueen
```

However, if you instead use double quotes when building the string, like so:

```
variable_b = "my\nname\nis\nOliver\nQueen"
```

the output of `puts variable_b` would be

```
>>my
>>name
>>is
>>Oliver
>>Queen
```

I am looking for a way in Javascript that does just what the single quotes do in Ruby, so that there will be less mistakes when trying to properly build a string that contains backslashes, and other characters that would 'break' the intended string.

Answer (score 2):

Single and double quotes in Javascript are equivalent. The only real reason to use one over the other is preference, and avoiding escaping embedded quotes, e.g.

```
"Don't need to escape this apostrophe."
```

or

```
'No need to escape this "quoted" word.'
```

Unless you are talking about JSON. In JSON you must use double quotes or it is considered a syntax error by many parsers.